# "making it knows" is not correct?

Tags: grammar

I know after third person singular verb forms
end in -s. For that reason I choose 3 but the right answer is 1

*1 making it known 

2 making it knowing

3 making it knows 

4 making it know*

please explain why?

Thank you in advance

Comment: The fact that the "third person singular verb form ends in **-s**" just means that for "ordinary" single-word verbs, we say *I eat, You eat, He **eats***. But ***to make something known*** is the infinitive of ***verb phrase***, that conjugates as *I **make** it known, He **makes** it known*. The ***known*** part is always a Past Participle, even in *He **will** make it known [when he gets the information himself]*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers isn't make the verb in this sentence and known working as a noun?

Comment: @WendyG: I don't know. We're probably at the point where I at least think the terminology has outlived its usefulness. Personally, I'd align *making it known* with *making it **clear*** - where you might want to call ***clear*** an "adjective", but to me it looks "adverbial". All I know is making things known or clear doesn't look much like making a case for something, or making a product.

Comment: @FumbleFingers i asked my son yesterday (who has just finished his GCSEs so still fresh in his mind) he said it was an adverb

Answer (score 1):

In this particular construction "make (something) (something)" there isn't a verb apart from "make", but other kinds of complement, for example:

> I'll **make him sorry**!

> It **makes me very happy** to hear that.

> **Make my drink a large one**!

> They **made it clear** that they would make no further concessions.

Here *known* is a past participle functioning as an adjective.

So *make* is the only verb functioning as a verb, and the only thing that can take a personal ending *-s*.

(More generally, when you have a complex verb phrase with a sequence of several verbs, only the first one can possibly take a personal ending: the other verbs will be either base form ("infinitive") or participles, depending on the construction they are in.)

Comment: isn't make actually the verb in those sentences?

Comment: Yes, @WendyG. I meant "doesn't take a verb apart from _make_". I've reworded it.